# React handling state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make an e-commerce app, and I've just started the project, but I keep getting an error. Every time i try to get the information from my data component and then map through it, I get 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'. can someone help me with that? Here are the components:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { Routes } from './routes'
import { Main } from './components/Main'
import { storeProducts } from './data/data'

function App() {

  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      setItems(storeProducts)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Routes />
       <Main items={items} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react'

import { ItemComponent } from './ItemComponent'

export const Main = ({items}) => {

    const products = items.map(() => <ItemComponent />)

    return (
        <div>
           {products}
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
import React from 'react'

export const ItemComponent = ({details}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello Item
        </div>
    )
}
```

data used

```
export const storeProducts = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Google Pixel - Black",
      img: "img/product-1.png",
      price: 10,
      company: "GOOGLE",
      info:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
      inCart: false,
      count: 0,
      total: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Samsung S7",
      img: "img/product-2.png",
      price: 16,
      company: "SAMSUNG",
      info:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
      inCart: false,
      count: 0,
      total: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "HTC 10 - Black",
      img: "img/product-3.png",
      price: 8,
      company: "htc",
      info:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
      inCart: false,
      count: 0,
      total: 0
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "HTC 10 - White",
      img: "img/product-4.png",
      price: 18,
      company: "htc",
      info:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
      inCart: false,
      count: 0,
      total: 0
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "HTC Desire 626s",
      img: "img/product-5.png",
      price: 24,
      company: "htc",
      info:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
      inCart: false,
      count: 0,
      total: 0
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: "Vintage Iphone",
      img: "img/product-6.png",
      price: 17,
      company: "apple",
      info:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
      inCart: false,
      count: 0,
      total: 0
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      title: "Iphone 7",
      img: "img/product-7.png",
      price: 30,
      company: "apple",
      info:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
      inCart: false,
      count: 0,
      total: 0
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      title: "Smashed Iphone",
      img: "img/product-8.png",
      price: 2,
      company: "apple",
      info:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juice sriracha paleo. Brooklyn sriracha semiotics, DIY coloring book mixtape craft beer sartorial hella blue bottle. Tote bag wolf authentic try-hard put a bird on it mumblecore. Unicorn lumbersexual master cleanse blog hella VHS, vaporware sartorial church-key cardigan single-origin coffee lo-fi organic asymmetrical. Taxidermy semiotics celiac stumptown scenester normcore, ethical helvetica photo booth gentrify.",
      inCart: false,
      count: 0,
      total: 0
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `console.log(storeProducts)` just before `setItems(storeProducts)`, to confirm that you are setting your state to what you think you are setting it to?  You could, for instance, have an import error.

Comment: Add `console.log(items)` to the line before the `return` statement in `App()`. What's the output?

Comment: By the way, you don't need a `useEffect` hook for that if you're just importing your data from another file. Just do `useState(storeProducts)` instead to set the initial state.

Comment: I console.log(items) and i got the array, but keep getting the error

Comment: Is that all the code there is? If it's an array, and assuming what you're showing is exactly what you have, this should work.

Comment: I know.. that's really strange. I have a router component too

Comment: The router has nothing to do with it - I think your mistake is somewhere else and you're not showing it in your code.

Comment: Are you using the create-react-app dev server?  If so perhaps try shutting it down, restarting, and doing a hard refresh (hold down the refresh button while the dev tools are open).  Although it's rare, the dev server can have issues with cached/stale code (and/or its source maps) that can make the browser show you the wrong thing.

Comment: I don't think so, the other components are things that I haven't used yet and they don't contain any information at all

Comment: I guess I'm really asking: are you using a "live server" of any sort (ie. when you save your `.js` files does your browser update immediately? do you have to run a command at the command line before you can see your site?)  The alternative would be that you somehow "compile" your React code ... or that you don't use JSX.  If you're not compiling, try restarting the program you run.

Comment: Everything seems to work with your code - https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-morning-9x1xg. Check your environment setup

Comment: It updates immediately

Comment: So have you tried stopping the program you run to make it update immediately, then restarting that program, *then* doing a "hard reload"?  Or you may not even need the hard reload, as restarting the program my open a fresh working tab; it just depends. (Or of course, if it wasn't the server's issue, this won't help at all.)

Comment: seems like i get the error only when i map over the array, because I typed {JSON.stringify(items)} and i got the results on screen

Comment: I dont know how to make the hard reload

Comment: Are you familiar with opening your developer tools?  It's `F12` in Chrome on most systems, or you can right-click on the page and choose "Inspect Element".  Once the tools are open, when you hold down your mouse on the "reload" button (the circular arrow on Chrome left of the URL bar), you should see an option to "Empty Cache and Hard Reload": click that.  This is a good trick to know about as a web dev in general, because there are other times when you'll need to clear your cache to see the fresh version of something you develop.

Answer (score 2):

Seems strange but try this:

```
export const Main = ({items}) => {

    if (!items) return <div/>

    const products = items.map(() => <ItemComponent />)

    return (
        <div>
           {products}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And see if it renders. setState is async and sometimes that causes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your error mean that you use **.map** function on a variable which has **undefined** value. Here I have some feedbacks to improve your code:

No need to use useEffect in App component:

```
function App() {   
  const [items, setItems] = useState(storeProducts);

  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Routes />
       <Main items={items} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And Main component:

```
export const Main = ({items}) => {
    const products = (items || []).map(() => <ItemComponent />)

    return (
        <div>
           {products}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**items || []** mean: if items is undefined then use empty array. And then no error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" anymore.